# How to handle nested event listeners javascript? (not about nested html elements)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need a function to trigger only after 2 events.
First event is onload, and second is onmessage coming from an iframe.

If onload and onmessage=="something"=> trigger that.
Otherwise => something else.

However, it seems that onload is executed before my onmessage. SO i need the 2 event to be nested. (Or not?)

Shoud I do like this:

```
     document.getElementById("myiframe").addEventListener("load", iframeLoaded, false);

        function iframeLoaded(){
        window.top.addEventListener("message", WhatisTheMessage, false);
        }

    function WhatisTheMessage(event){
 window.top.removeEventListener("message", WhatisTheMessage, false);

    if(event.date=="something"){//do something}
    else if(event.date=="somethingelse"){//do somethingelse}
    }
```

Does it seem correct? The problem that appear to me is that if "message" is arriving before (I think it is not is not possible), I don't listen to it.

Comment: At first use "window" instead of "window.top"

Comment: It will not work because it is coming from an iframe. I think it is not an issue anyway.

Comment: If youre inside of an iframe, use window.top to get the parent site. On the parent side just use window

Comment: By `Otherwise`, do you mean if only `load` event is fired? I'm not sure why don't you just bind `message` event?

Comment: You want to listen to the message that is sent to the parent. So use window

Answer (score 1):

```
window.addEventlistener("load",test,false);
window.addEventlistener("message",test,false);
var counter=0;
 function test(event){
  counter++;
  if(counter==2){
   //two event listeners called
  }
 }
```